# PubNub failing with com.pubnub.api.PubNubException: null, what's going on?

Tags: java, pubnub

I have an application that works fine on my own computer and on Heroku, but in another machine it's failing with this error:

```
com.pubnub.api.PubNubException: null
    at com.pubnub.api.PubNubException$PubNubExceptionBuilder.build(PubNubException.java:9) ~[pubnub-gson-4.19.0.jar:na]
    at com.pubnub.api.endpoints.Endpoint.sync(Endpoint.java:107) ~[pubnub-gson-4.19.0.jar:na]
    at tech.dashman.server.PubNubPool.grant(PubNubPool.java:55) ~[classes/:na]
```

PubNubPool.java:55 contains this:

```
ttl.sync();
```

and the context for it is:

```
public void grant(Agent agent) throws PubNubException {
    Grant ttl = pubNubs.
            get().
            grant().
            channels(agent.getPubNubChannels()).
            authKeys(Collections.singletonList(agent.getPubNubAuthKey())).
            write(false).
            read(true).
            ttl(0);
    ttl.sync();
}
```

Any ideas what could be going on here?

Comment: We would need PubNub logs to investigate further. Can you [enable PubNub Java client logging](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/java-se-java/pubnub-java-sdk-troubleshooting-guide) and send the log file to [PubNub Support](https://support.pubnub.com) and include this SO link so we can post back an answer?

Comment: What is the environment details of the other machine?

Comment: just checking in to see if you still need assistance with this. [Contact PubNub Support](https://support.pubnub.com) directly if needed.

Comment: Did you contact PubNub support about? Or find resolution?

Comment: I contacted support and tried to make them understand that we cannot enable Pubnub Java Client logging and send them logs because the crashes are happening on the production build and they are not replicable. So far no response from their engineering team. Frustrating...